# Does the shape of subarea affect the performance in GPU computation?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

Assume using OpenCL as API.

Assume having a 2D array of size `1024*1024`. Now we want to do something on one of its sub-area. We know that there is no actually 2D array inside memory; only 1D array, but 2D's row major or column major form. As such, a sub-area of shape `1024*1` is very different from shape `1*1024`. Depending on using row major or column major form, one of these 2 shape is an actual continuous array and the other one is 1024 discrete dots, where between each adjacent element there is a `1023 * sizeof(datatype)` gap.

The question is, is there any performance different on such 2 situations?

A more advanced question based on this, does the following 2 functions have different performance? Well I could actually get the answer by running them, but I would like to see the detailed reason.

```
enqueueNDRangeKernel(doSomething,offset(0,0),globalSize(1024,1024), workGroupSize(1,1024));
enqueueNDRangeKernel(doSomething,offset(0,0),globalSize(1024,1024), workGroupSize(1024,1));
```

---

I have some interesting result to share:

```
//Kernel function is a simple +1; 2D array is float[8192][8192]; result is ns by CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_[END-START]

WorkingArea:(1,8192), LocalGroup:(1,1024):
result is: 4096
result is: 6880
result is: 4096
result is: 7040
result is: 3840
result is: 11264
result is: 7072
result is: 6912
result is: 4096
result is: 3936
result is: 4096
result is: 6720
result is: 11264
result is: 30720
result is: 11264
result is: 6976

WorkingArea:(32,8192), LocalGroup:(1,1024):
result is: 8192
result is: 14336
result is: 14016
result is: 13248
result is: 13312
result is: 13216
result is: 9216
result is: 13216
result is: 9216
result is: 19392
result is: 9216
result is: 9920
result is: 27744
result is: 7168
result is: 6272
result is: 7168

WorkingArea:(32,8192), LocalGroup:(32, 32):
result is: 22528
result is: 30720
result is: 30336
result is: 29728
result is: 30720
result is: 25600
result is: 30368
result is: 30496
result is: 25600
result is: 29696
result is: 28672
result is: 30720
result is: 22624
result is: 26240
result is: 26304
result is: 25536

WorkingArea:(8192,1), LocalGroup:(1024,1):
result is: 5120
result is: 8288
result is: 13312
result is: 8192
result is: 13088
result is: 8192
result is: 8288
result is: 9152
result is: 8192
result is: 13152
result is: 13152
result is: 12288
result is: 8192
result is: 8192
result is: 8192
result is: 13312

WorkingArea:(8192,32), LocalGroup:(1024,1):
result is: 28672
result is: 32512
result is: 31712
result is: 32448
result is: 31744
result is: 32480
result is: 32544
result is: 31744
result is: 28512
result is: 31744
result is: 31616
result is: 31744
result is: 36736
result is: 39744
result is: 32480
result is: 28672

WorkingArea:(8192,32), LocalGroup:(32,32):
result is: 22528
result is: 25504
result is: 25536
result is: 22400
result is: 23552
result is: 25248
result is: 22528
result is: 32416
result is: 29696
result is: 30304
result is: 29696
result is: 51200
result is: 22528
result is: 36864
result is: 25344
result is: 22528

WorkingArea:(8192,8192), LocalGroup:(1,1024):
result is: 1462304
result is: 1466048
result is: 1461824
result is: 1461952
result is: 1462272
result is: 1465344
result is: 2147328
result is: 1750016
result is: 1712896
result is: 1465184
result is: 1465344
result is: 1465184
result is: 1471456
result is: 1466080
result is: 1466240
result is: 1461248

WorkingArea:(8192,8192), LocalGroup:(1024,1):
result is: 14011392
result is: 11673280
result is: 11722560
result is: 11153120
result is: 12884992
result is: 11982464
result is: 10938368
result is: 10518528
result is: 11044864
result is: 10567680
result is: 10782720
result is: 10988544
result is: 11358208
result is: 10978304
result is: 11260928
result is: 11233984

WorkingArea:(8192,8192), LocalGroup:(32,32):
result is: 4443136
result is: 4447072
result is: 4794368
result is: 4631552
result is: 4835104
result is: 4982784
result is: 4439616
result is: 4426752
result is: 4438720
result is: 4892416
result is: 4482048
result is: 4692672
result is: 5634048
result is: 4432480
result is: 4477920
result is: 4654080
```

There are a few interesting and noticable comparison:

WorkingArea:(1,8192) and WorkingArea:(32,8192); With same partition but different work load: they are linear scaling work load, but only minor scaling on the time cost, 16x load vs ~1.5x time cost.

A general tendency is, as (1, 1024) goes to (1024, 1), time cost monotonically increases, up to ~8x. (32, 32) is ~3x of (1, 1024), but 3 is very close to $\sqrt(8)$ so the actual value I would guess it to be $sqrt(8)$.

Answer (score 0):

There are various arguments to consider here.

1. Cache Locality
2. Latency Hiding
3. Proportion Of Time Reading/Writing From RAM
4. Hardware Differences

Cache locality of the data can make a meaningful difference in performance between row-major or column-major data. If, for example, you had 1024x1024 double precision floats, that's 8MB which is more than a lot of GPUs have in shared cache, though newer ones can have much more. Cache misses can slow things down quite a bit, 10x is not unusual. Reading contiguous data might be possible at a lower cache level giving lower latency.

GPUs run lots of threads in parallel and no GPU yet has 1,000,000 cores, so even latency due to cache misses can, to some extent, be 'hidden' (mitigated) by switching threads in and out of execution to keep the cores occupied. This, I think, is one reason why for a long time, GPUs had much less cache than CPUs even thought they had many more 'cores'.

If what your kernel is doing with the data takes much longer than it takes to read and write the data from or to global memory, then you won't notice much difference in overall performance of the job.

In my experience writing OpenCL programs, it can be very difficult to estimate the performance of an application without actually running it on the hardware you want to test. Architectural differences between GPUs can give unexpected differences in performance so it's worth testing different types of GPUs to see what works best for the application. Even GPUs that have the same generation of memory can give unexpectedly different performance.

Comment: So basically we come to: don't think about optimization too much. If the job is simple like doing some arithmatic on each element, just wrap everything in one function and enqueue with NullRange, letting OpenCL runtime automatically choose how to divide the job.

Comment: I would still set a range as local range parameters can affect performance. You can compare results with NullRange I guess, but I've never actually used that so can't comment about it. One thing I forgot to mention is sometimes you get HIGHER performance doing it the way you would expect to be slower. I think that OpenCL must use locks somehow in a way that can can hurt the performance of processing contiguous data. You really just have to try it.

Comment: I posted my test result and make some observation. I would be very interested to hear your comment about them.

Comment: float[8192][8192]; is 256MB you're probably getting lots of cache misses doing it the 'wrong' way giving you the 8x time increase, which is about what I said. You probably should say what hardware you're using for the results to be more interesting. Could you explain in more detail where your comment about 16x workload comes from because I didn't get what you meant.

Comment: This is on NV RTX 3060TI; Actually doing a 8192*8192 array is what I am interested with; This array is a temperature simulation and I would like to increase the simulation precision/resolution as much as possible; lowering down to 1024*1024 may be not very satisfiying on the result.

Comment: You said about cache miss. That's one of my question: With different functions enqueues that enqueue the same function; will the runtime be able to assign the same division to the same compute unit so that it can utilized its nearby cache (where cached previous run's result)?

Comment: I dont think the answer to my cache question is true. From my experiment, calling one kernel function reapeated does not give any performance improvment on repeated calls. So to utilize cache, we must let the kernel function stay alive and not return.

Comment: You raise an interesting question - Is the data in the shared cache of a GPU kept between kernel calls? I know the local memory is not, but I don't remember ever reading information about what happens to cached global memory when a kernel finishes. This might be something hardware dependent. Maybe you could try running the code on your CPU to see if it behaves similarly. Some modern high end CPUs can have over 256MB of L3 cache, so you might be able to do your operation faster on a CPU than a GPU.